# Importing .vue files in typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I am trying to setup a Vue3 project with Typescript.
I get the error: **"File '/home/.../src/App.vue.ts' is not a module"**.

When using Javascript in `main.js`, it works fine, but when renaming it to `main.ts`, I am unable to import ".vue" files.
Main.ts:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Now, when running `yarn serve`, the output shows:

```
ERROR in src/main.ts:2:17
TS2306: File '/home/.../src/App.vue.ts' is not a module.
    1 | import { createApp } from 'vue';
  > 2 | import App from './App.vue';
      |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
    3 | import router from './router';
```

What is the way to make Typescript understand `.vue`-files?

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that I should add "export default {}" to my `App.vue` file.

The original (faulty) App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
console.log('Loading App.vue');
</script>
```

I fixed the error by adding "export default {};".
The new App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
console.log('Loading App.vue');

export default {}; // <-- added this line to fix the error
</script>
```

Comment: `<script>` tag is optional in a `.vue` file. But, when it's missing, the framework provides a default export. So you can't just add one for logging. If you add it, it has to export the component logic, whether it's Options API, Composition API, or the `<script setup>` macro (which is an alternative, removing some boilerplate)... To better understand what Vue does behind the scenes, play in the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/) and peek at the JS tab.

Answer (score 2):

App.vue must be:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
<script>
```

or

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {};
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).